# How to read a property of a value passed by reference?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to script OmniGraffle 5.3.6 where I try to read the `layers` element of a `canvas` that I have passed to a function (or handler, in AppleScript parlance). When I run the following:

```
on exportToPng(theCanvas)
    set layerCount to count of layers of theCanvas
end exportToPng

tell application "OmniGraffle Professional 5"
    set theDocument to front document
    set allCanvases to canvases of theDocument
    set theCanvas to item 1 of allCanvases
    my exportToPng(theCanvas)
end tell
```

I get the following error:

```
  error "OmniGraffle Professional 5 got an error: Can’t make |layers| of
  canvas id 1 of document \"base-dependency-diagram.graffle\" into type reference."
  number -1700 from |layers| of canvas id 1 of document
  "base-dependency-diagram.graffle" to reference
```

However, if I were to inline my function, then everything works fine:

```
tell application "OmniGraffle Professional 5"
    set theDocument to front document
    set allCanvases to canvases of theDocument
    set theCanvas to item 1 of allCanvases
    set layerCount to count of layers of theCanvas
end tell
```

I read [Passing by Reference Versus Passing by Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW4), but I did not find it helpful. It's pretty sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass by reference. However, wherever you pass it must also have "tell application" so that application can handle the passed reference. So you will want your function like this...

```
on exportToPng(theCanvas)
    tell application "OmniGraffle Professional 5"
      set layerCount to count of layers of theCanvas
    end tell
end exportToPng
```

After all, only "OmniGraffle Professional 5" knows how to get the layers from theCanvas.